# Is there a way to protect ("lock") an MS Word Document such that even selection is disabled?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, password-protection, copy-protection, keystrokes

I'm looking for a way to completely "lock" up a Word document, so that users won't have the option of selecting the text and copying/pasting to other application.  Ideally, I would like to code a VBA script that disables the keyboard input altogether, thereby preventing Print and Copy/Paste shortcut key combos.  I haven't been able to find any comprehensive VBA solutions yet.  I realize that even achieving this goal would not prevent a user from taking a print screen of the document, or finding some other crafty way of reproducing the information in the document, although that's fine for my purposes.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why not save it as protected PDF? You get exactly what you want, and it looks still the same.

Comment: The reason I need to keep it as a Word doc is because the content needs to be readily accessible by a list of non tech-savvy managers who will be making documented revisions and track their changes.  If I convert to PDF, I lose the ability to track changes in Word without re-converting it back to a Word Document.  I'm writing a work order to this effect for them to follow, and it needs to be as simple as possible.  Does that make sense?  I found that by protecting the document to allow form-filling actually does the trick (re: copy/paste).  VBA helped prevent print commands from going through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to go here is using a protected PDF.

As you mentioned, just protecting the document using form filling capabilities only, the document will be protected as you would like it to happen.

EDIT: old information for reference purposes only:
If you really need to stick with Microsoft Word for some odd reason, consider adding a transparent image that covers the entire document, then protect the document against editing. If people then want to select text they'll click on the image instead, and as such won't be able to select text.

They can still press CTRL-A to select all, copy it to a new document and then edit it though, that won't be possible to prevent. Not even with VBA. A protective PDF does not have that limitation.

And not a lot of people will think that CTRL-A will work, as the feedback trying to select something would make them think the document is protected. Of course, editing it yourself is tricky too. You need to move the image aside first.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion; perhaps I could use this notion in other contexts of my development projects.  I found out that protecting the document only to allow form-filling actually prevents any text from being selected, therefore also from being copy/pasted.  This seems to be doing the trick perfectly so far.  In my response to the previous comment, I mention the reason I believe it best to keep the file as a Word doc, rather than converting to PDF.

Comment: I should also mention that my document contains no form objects whatsoever - this doesn't prevent me from enabling protection for form filling, consequently enabling the "selection protection" behaviour I was seeking in my original post.

Comment: @markddelorme I've edited my answer accordingly so you can mark your question as answered and let everyone know you no longer seek help. Glad to hear you got it resolved.